# Build and validate a REST json request using a openAPI/swagger schema using VSCode

Tags: json, rest, visual-studio-code, schema, openapi

I'm using Visual Studio Code to write REST json requests, I'm validating pretty complex schemas as I type on VSCode mapping against the "json.schemas" in settings.

Lately, the REST API's grew up in complexity and I'm no longer receive a regular json schema but a YAML swagger 2.0 file.

How can I validate as I type using Intellisense and build from scratch a request in Visual Studio Code as I did it in the past? I'm trying to use OpenAPI extension on VSCode but it's not working for me. Thank you!

Installed openAPI and yaml extensions in Visual Studio Code.